# downloading multiple files from a dict. using multithreading

Tags: python, python-multithreading

i am trying to do multiple downloads at same time . i have create a list of dictionary with path where file will be downloaded and list of download urls or single url like this :

```
testList = [{'/test/doc/': ['http://firstfile.tar',
 'http://secondfile.tar']},{'/test/doc/file1': ['http://ulr/somefile.zip', 'http:// another file.zip']}, {'/test1': 'http://newfile.tar'}]
```

i am able to iterate through this list to a download via wget but it is happening one by one .
is there a way to use multithread to achieve say 10 downloads at a time .
so that my program completes faster. i came to know that due to GIL we cannot use multithreading like we can in java . so any help or any example.
Thanks.

Comment: Asyncio is a good fit.

Comment: any examples will be great .